# Performance Profiling of OpenGL Shaders

Tags: opengl, profiling, glsl

Is there a tool available that can do performance profiling of OpenGL shaders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nVidia [PerfWorks](https://developer.nvidia.com/perfworks) can. They also have [FX Composer](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/fx_composer_home.html), which includes some profiling with a graphical front-end (but FX Composer is now basically discontinued--you can still download it, but it's no longer being updated).

AMD/ATI's [GPUPerfAPI](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/GPUPerfAPI/Pages/default.aspx) and [GPUPerfStudio](https://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-perfstudio/) provide similar capabilities. They also have  [GPU ShaderAnalyzer](https://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-shaderanalyzer/) to do static analysis, but I believe it's restricted to DirectX shaders, not OpenGL.

Comment: NVIDIA ShaderPerf is now called/part of NVIDIA PerfKit: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfkit

Comment: @JakubNarębski: Thanks--updated.

Comment: And [PerfWorks](https://developer.nvidia.com/perfworks) is the successor to Perfkit.

Comment: PerfStudio moved to https://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-perfstudio/.

Comment: Perfkit is readily available though while PerfWorks is "evaluation on request". But it's integrated into MS PIX if you use DirectX.

Comment: Is the situation really that bad? Are there no real shader profilers out there?
Something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkcwk.png

Answer (score 0):

If you run on Nvidia hardware there is also [Nsight for Visual Studio](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition) resp. the standalone [Nsight Graphics](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics).

AMD's [GPUPerfStudio](https://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-perfstudio/) even works without AMD hardware but you only get the API tracer (and the static shader analyzer if you use DirectX). The frame debugger and profiler tools depend on their hardware of course.

For Intel there is [GPA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/gpa/graphics-frame-analyzer). It doesn't support shader micro profiling though.
There is also the static (i.e. does not require hardware) [Intel Shader Analyzer](https://github.com/GameTechDev/IntelShaderAnalyzer) but not sure if it provides more than just the assembly: http://shader-playground.timjones.io/749ef0d908128a0ae8a824b93381bbf1

RenderDoc does not really have profiling capabilities [at this point](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc/issues?q=label%3AProfiling) due to lack of time.
But some [Intel perf counters](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc/pull/1136) for OpenGL have been added recently.